# ClientBuilder not found

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to build a jersey client that sends a get request to a RESTful webservice.
But i obtain the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder
    at helper.RestClient.<init>(RestClient.java:23)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

I use the following gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile group: 'com.google.actions', name: 'actions-on-google', version: '1.+'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.14.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.31'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.31'
}
```

This is the code of my jersey client:

```
package helper;

import domain.Medication;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class RestClient {
    private static final String REST_URI = <URL>
    private Client client;

    public RestClient() {
        client  = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    }

    public Medication fetchMedication(String id, String token) {
        return client
                .target(REST_URI)
                .path("medications/" + id)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                .get(Medication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: So... did you download the javax.ws.rs jar file?

Comment: I tried to add the javax.ws.rs via `compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1.1'`. But still doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like an IDE issue. Try to clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: I use IntelliJ. I invalidated caches, restarted and rebuilt. But still the same error.

Comment: I don't know a ton about Jersey, but Jersey seems to come with its own version of Client and ClientBuilder in the `jersey-client` that you're using. Are you using sample code that was meant to be used with javax.ws.rs and not Jersey? If that's the case, could converting the code to use Jersey's JerseyClient and JerseyClientBuilder be an option?

Comment: I converted the code to use JerseyClient and JerseyClientBuilder. It's the same error but now for `org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a problem with gradle in my project.
I switched to maven and i got it working.